# Android CheckJNI: JNIEnv*s: using a JNIEnv* from the wrong thread SIGABRT

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-native-interface

I have a method being called periodically via JNI through a ScheduledExecutorService of only one thread.

I have an occasional crash with no real steps to reproduce yet. 
This is the stack trace:

```
06-12 00:36:12.608 17530 17530 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[40,tid=16967,Native,Thread*=0x7e8d345400,
peer=0x13958280,"pool-12-thread-1"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[40,tid=16967,Native,Thread*=0x7e8d345400,peer=0x13958280,"pool-12-thread-1"]'
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000006bb2c  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0000000000068f4c  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000023f58  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000000000001c810  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0000000000433ad4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+464)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000000e5a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1592)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00000000002f080c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+2200)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00000000002f0af4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+124)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0000000000102718  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+156)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 0000000000101fb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+168)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00000000000ffc68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+1124)
06-12 00:36:12.621 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 00000000001055e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI13CheckCallArgsERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessERNS_11ScopedCheckEP7_JNIEnv
P8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_10InvokeTypeEPKNS_7VarArgsE+140)
06-12 00:36:12.622 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00000000001048a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_li
stNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+704)
06-12 00:36:12.622 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 00000000000f7658  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI15CallVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+96)
06-12 00:36:12.622 17530 17530 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 0000000000005118  /data/app/com.abc.xyz/lib/arm64/libtest.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv14CallVoidMethodEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDz+148)
```

After doing some investigation, this is an abort when a thread is using a different JNIEnv* or the thread is not attached to the JNIEnv.

I am not sure how this is possible because:
a) I am not caching the JNIEnv* anywhere, and passing it through methods.
b) I do not need to attach this thread since I am calling this via a jni method.
c) In the error message,

```
Thread[40,tid=16967,Native,Thread*=0x7e8d345400,
peer=0x13958280,"pool-12-thread-1"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[40,tid=16967,Native,Thread*=0x7e8d345400,peer=0x13958280,"pool-12-thread-1"]
```

Both threads are the same, as I expected. How is this happening?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the relevant native code and java code?